# html разметка facebook каждый раз меняется?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать javascript который выдернет все посты со страницы facebook.

Заметил что там какое-то не человеческое название блоков в которые обернуты посты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я полагаю что названия этих блоков автоматически каким-то образом меняются. Это так? И если да, как тогда выдернуть блоки с постами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там используется React и скорее всего при каждом обновлении функционала сборщик пересобирает, по ему понятным установлен параметрам название, классов на них вам полагаться нельзя. Можете попробовать поискать id и уже от них плясать